# Deleted a part of a dynamic drive and the whole drive is unallocated now, how to recover?

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery, partition-recovery, dynamic-disk, recovery

From my old hdd I deleted the old partitions of windows(50 gb) and ubuntu(75 gb) and the space was unallocated(125 gb) there was another partition(HDD STUFF) which i didn't do anything to. then I installed that hdd on my new laptop(With windows 10 on ssd), and using disk management I merged the the HDD STUFF with the 125 gb unallocated space and it asked me that it will need to convert it to dynamic disk> I clicked yes. It bacame one drive in the file explorer but showed as two partitions in disk management with the same drive letter. This partition was working with windows but not in ubuntu. So deleted the partition without data i.i the 125 gb using the disk management but the whole disk became unallocated.

How to recover my partition?

I tried to look for many answers and came up with some softwares like easeus, test disk, minitool and others(partition recovery tools, I didn't try data recovery of easeus).

Test disk can identify my partition(as whole 465 gb disk including the 125 from others) but i says that its size is more than the disk so it can't be recovered, and minitool gives invalid configure file error when i click apply.

I've attached screenshots for both.

how can I recover the partition table as to get back the drive, or if that't not possible please tell me how to get my data.

I've not created any partition from that disk, left it as it is so no data is overwritten i guess.

Here are some screenshots of test disk and minitool.

Disk 1 is the hdd and HDD STUFF is to be recovered.

[Test disk quick search result with my partition at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9WYe.png)

[HDD seems too small error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggAnZ.png)

[Minitool search result with my partition at the bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AEUtt.png)

[invalid configure file error after clicking apply](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f2Q5G.png)

I have Ubuntu installed as well, tell me if something can be done in that if not in windows.

Comment: Try [this procedure](https://www.sevenforums.com/hardware-devices/223018-recover-unallocated-dynamic-volume-post2489791.html#post2489791).

Comment: As in step 3 of this procedure. Clicking apply gives the invalid configure file error, shown in the screenshot I uploaded.

Comment: @harrymc if you see that screenshot of minitool with the error (The 4th screenshot) you'll notice that the size of disk 1 is 465 gb and there is unallocated space of 125 gb and also a partition that i want to recover of 465 gb, which is not possibe obviously as disk space cant be less then the sum of partitions. I believe that is what is creating the invalid configure file error, same thing with testdisk.

Comment: Try the trial version of MiniTool Partition Wizard Pro or Pro Ultimate, as dynamic disk operations are not supported by free edition. Try also [iCare](https://www.icare-recovery.com/#).

Comment: This is the pro version. I’ll guess I’ll try icare. Is icare for data recovery or to recover partition with file system?